# sailsJs mongodb connection error in docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, sails.js

Unable to connect sailsJs dockerimage to mongodb.
I am having issue while connecting mongodb running on local machine, not as mongo image.

mongodb is running on localhost:27017

```
error: Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.  Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running?

 Error details: {
     Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0 .0 .1: 27017
     at Object.exports._errnoException(util.js: 1020: 11)
     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort(util.js: 1043: 20)
     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect[as oncomplete](net.js: 1090: 14)
     name: 'MongoError',
     message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the container is running in a docker engine in the same host where your MongoDB server is running, you should try to run your docker container using `--net=host` if you want your container to be able to reach 127.0.0.1/localhost in the same host. I nice answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach).

If you're using docker engine in a VM you may have to change the localhost IP for the public/private IP assigned to your mongodb server host.

Comment: tried with --net=host it didnt work.
any example for connecting localhost inside container will be helpful.

Comment: What OS are you using for your mongo server and your docker engine?

Comment: locally i am using MAC and server is ubuntu

Comment: If using MacOS please use the answer I linked in my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) where you have a solution for MacOS.